# objective c - Access private var from public function

Tags: ios, objective-c

Newbie to objective C...

NOTE: This is a conceptual problem, as I'm trying to translate "public and private" from what I know about other languages.

How can I access the "stringB" ivar through the "public" method?

myClass.h

```
@interface myClass : UIViewController {

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringA;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringB;

- (void)dealWithStringA;
+ (void)dealWithStringB;
```

myClass.m

```
#import "myClass.h"

@interface myClass () {

}
@end

@implementation myClass

// My "private" function
- (void)dealWithStringA
{
    return _stringA;
}

// My "public" function
+ (void)dealWithStringB
{
    // Errors with: Instance variable "stringB" accessed in class method
    return _stringB;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz, you cleared up my thinking.... just trying to get a grip based on what I know from other languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrong with understanding "+", "-" - it's not about private / public.

To have a private function you should implement that in your .m file:

```
@interface YourClass ()
- (id) privateMethod;
@end
```

Everything you declare in .h file will be public:

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject
- (id)someMethod //public
@end
```

"+" is used for static functions so you can call them without having an instance of a class. 
For example in your case:

```
[myClass dealWithStringB];
```

and for "-" function you need instance.

```
[[[myClass alloc] init] dealWithStringA];
```

The static functions can be used when you don't need any properties from a class or to they are pretty often used to create instances of classes.

Answer (score 2):

The method starting with a `+` is called a class method in objective C where a method starting with `-` is an instance method. An instance method can be performed on an instance of that class only.

Also the return type for your method would be an `NSString` since you are expecting to get a string object from that method.

For a class method, you'll need to create an autoreleasing instance of that class and then perform operations on that instance.

For eg.

```
+ (NSString*)dealWithStringB
{
    MyClass *myClass = [[[MyClass alloc] init] autorelease];
    myClass.stringB = @"Its String B";//It's an absurd example 
    return myClass.stringB;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The "+" prefix means class method, not public. A "-" stands for instance method, not private.

Both public and private methods can access the private state of the class or instance.

Answer (score 0):

myClass.h (Similar to yours)

```
@interface myClass : UIViewController
   {

   }

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringA;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *stringB;

- (void)dealWithStringA;
+ (void)dealWithStringB;

 @end
```

myClass.m

```
 @implementation myClass
 @synthesize stringA ;
 @synthesize stringB ;

 static myClass* instance = nil;
 +(void) dealWithStringB
   {
       if(instance==nil)
        {
           instance=[myClass alloc]init];
        }

        else
         {
            //Access the field this way
                  printf("@"The string content is %@",instance.stringB);
         } 

   }
```

Hope its Clear!!!